# How to stop tween from tweening in as3

Tags: actionscript-3

I have an tween:

```
TweenLite.to(s, 0.1, {x:100, y:100});
```

But I want it to stop tweening and go to:

```
    x = 10;
    y = 10;
```

so I use this code:
    s.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onClick);

```
function onClick(e:MouseEvent):void
{
    s.x = 10;
    s.y = 10;
}
```

But the tween keeps tweening and doesn't stop can someone help me with this?

This is the code I simplified but it still doesn't work:

```
stop();
import com.greensock.*; 
import com.greensock.easing.*;
import com.greensock.TweenMax;
import com.greensock.TweenLite;
import flash.events.Event;
import com.greensock.TweenLite

stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, rijden); // Add the button click

function rijden(e:MouseEvent):void {

TweenLite.to(auto, 4, {x:666.15, y:375.6});
}
addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, einde1);
function einde1(e:Event){
    if(auto.hitTestObject(stopauto)){
   var myTween=TweenLite.to(auto, 4, {x:666.15, y:375.6});
myTween.kill();     //here code for tween killing
trace("works")
        //
        auto.x = 241;
        auto.y = 375;
       removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, einde1)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could assign TweenLite instance to variable like this

```
var myTween=TweenLite.to(s, 0.1, {x:100, y:100});
```

and after that kill it with

```
myTween.kill();
```

About your comments it should be like this

```
addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, einde1);
function einde1(e:Event){
    if(auto.hitTestObject(eind)){
        //here code for tween killing

        //
        man.x = 241.3;
        man.y = 375;
        removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, einde1)
    }
}
```

**UPD:** Problem was in your Timer. You didn't stop it after it should. Also i changed 3 enterFrame listeners to one. Anyway, link to your fixed code sample - https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/39984632/stackoverflowtest.fla

**UPD2:** To make lives counter you could this. Add

```
var lives:Number=5;
```

And change this one:

```
if(auto.hitTestObject(man) && !autoWasHitByMan){
    trace("auto hits man");
    autoWasHitByMan=true;
    TweenLite.to(man, 4, {x:539.95, y:145, rotation:360});
}
```

to this

```
if(auto.hitTestObject(man) && !autoWasHitByMan){
    trace("auto hits man");
    lives--;
    TweenLite.to(man, 4, {x:539.95, y:145, rotation:360});
    if(lives==0){
        autoWasHitByMan=true;
    }
}
```

Comment: the event "kill" isn't in the file of greensock so it can't be find: Error #1069: Property kill not found on gs.TweenLite and there is no default value.

Comment: it's funny because here it is - [link]api.greensock.com/as/com/greensock/core/Animation.html#kill();

I ran test just now, everythink worked right. By you error report, looks like you are using some other than standart greensock tweening platform build. It should be com.greensock.TweenLite. Maybe it is some cut version?

Comment: how can I inport the greensock file correctly? because every time I get an error

Comment: First of all download it here [link]http://www.greensock.com/dl/greensock-v12-as3.zip
Place com folder from archive to the same folder your *.fla is.
Add `import com.greensock.TweenLite` to the frame where you want use it or to the Document class.

Comment: Are you sure its not a `hitTestObject();` problem?

Comment: this is my code: addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, einde1);
function einde1(e:Event){
 if(auto.hitTestObject(eind)){
  man.x = 241.3;
     man.y = 375;
  
  
  }}
I think it is an problem in the setting of my code but I can't figure out what it is, I'am doing it exactly the same with an other object nd it works fine but for some reason this doesn't want to work

Comment: Put trace inside `if(..){//here}` to see if it fires. And try to make hitTest work without tweens (just place where you need). After that add tweens and stuff.

Comment: @Asprio I have tried it with trace and it works but I get an whole list of the trace word so if I put it like this if(..){trace("works")} I got this as result:works
works
works
works
works
works
works
works
works
works
works
works
works
works
works
works
works
works
works
works
works
works
works
works
works
works
works
works
works
works
works
works
works
works
works

Comment: this explains why the tween kept going but what next??

Comment: it should shout "works" only then _auto_ actually intersect with _eind_. And you `man.x = 241.3; man.y = 375;` statement should only only call once. For that you could remove listener inside `if` using 'removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, einde1);`

Comment: I don't really get it should it be like this:addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, einde1);
function einde1(e:Event){
 removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, einde1);{
  trace("works")
  
  
  }} ?? because now the hitTesObject isnt called anymore

Comment: I put it like this: addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, einde1);
function einde1(e:Event){if(auto.hitTestObject(eind)){
 removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, einde1);{
  trace("works")
  auto.x = 241.3;
     auto.y = 375;
  
  }}} but it doesn't work, I get the trace but the object doesn't goe to the x and y coordinates

Comment: Now i dont understand which object should go to the coords. Before that you used _man_, now its _auto_.

Comment: thanks, but for some reason the car seems not to hit the object, it traces "works" but nothing happens

Comment: If it traces "works" inside your `if` construction with `hitTestObject` condition, then according to ac3 its hit it. There are some kind of simple mistake but its really hard to find it then you don't see all code you write and how it executes. It will be lot easier if you upload your project somewhere.

Comment: it is very strange I have simplyfied my code and took out the code that I needed to test if auto works with the hitTestObject. I tested some times with the killing tween code and without it but none of it worked, although it traces "works", it is an mystery for me I will update the code so maybe you can test some or see what the problem is

Comment: I have putted my code in a fiddle so you can take a look at it: http://jsfiddle.net/kQfAp/

Comment: It's not only question of code. Your objects structure matters too, so it really helps if you upload fla somewhere.

Comment: is that really necessary? You can use some random objects right? All my objects are movieclips, and you can see which objects hit eachother, right?

Comment: It is necessary because if i write my own example with my own MovieClips im sure that hitTestObject will work and i could kill tween whenever I want. I don't know what you MovieClips are, where are they, what they structure is and what processes they exposed to other than you code. And all this information - matters. If you wish, you could isolate just two objects to test in new file, create you code and send it.

Comment: yes I have done that already and I think that the problem s that i use "on enterframe" to much, but i don't have enough knowledge to use an other event in combination with hittestobject

Comment: As i said earlier you should remove listeners after successed with hitTestObject, otherwise it will shoot it many time which could cause trouble.

Comment: here I have an fla document for you as you asked: https://www.dropbox.com/s/bywncjn21t1c4gz/stackoverflowtest.fla

Comment: how can I var myValue:Number = 5; add myValue--;
trace(myValue); for lives to the (auto.hitTestObject(man) && !autoWasHitByMan) because I can't stop the function with removeaddlistener

Comment: Don't understood you question)

Comment: I Want to add lives so myvalue are the Lives so there are 5 lives and each time auto hits man one live has to 5 minus 1 but because the hit function is on enterframe it keeps repeating all the numbers, but I can't use removeaddlistener because it doesn't works anymore

Comment: can you help me with that according to you're file?

Comment: this doesn't work I get this: start car timer
2005
shootCar
auto hits man
game over
auto hits man
game over
auto hits man
game over
auto hits man
game over
auto hits man
auto hits stopauto I think this is because it is an addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME and you can't remove it

Comment: And what is not working? You get five hits auto with man, after that it stops check hits and move auto to your point. Looks like you put `game over` not to the right place. You should understand how this script work and in which order it executes, otherwise you will ask questions to every single change you want to make. Just place lot of traces inside or start debuger with breakpoint in all functions and you will see.

Comment: I get this when car and man hit only one time but every time that auto and man hit a live has to be "destroyed" so if man and auto hit 5-1=4 live if man and auto hit again 4-1=3 lives and so on till lives=0

Comment: It describes how it work now. But where is no code to car go back and start over, so add it. Now all 5 hits happen it one moment coz car still there.

Comment: I don't know a code to go back and start over?? or I don't know what you mean

Comment: place car back to it original coodinates, start same tween again

Comment: Yes I did that it works fine but for some reason it repeats hitting

Comment: You can check it with the file you send me I added killtween and an other x and y coordinates but otherwise I don't know what the problem is??

Comment: can you help me with the problem that if car and man hit each other that car goes back earlier than men and if I click the stage, timer is already running while actually it should be like this: if man is back in place and you click on stage timer starts and car starts with the tween.

Comment: can you explain to me how I can remove the hit event because I have made an next level on the next frame but the event on the first frame keep going

Comment: You can use `removeEventListener` or add (&&) to hitTest expression some boolean trigger which you set to `false` at second level.

Comment: what kind of boolean trigger do you mean?

Comment: just a variable `if(auto.hitTestObject(man) && !autoWasHitByMan && trigger)` then it false, all expression is false so nothing happens

Answer (score 1):

You might try:

```
TweenLite.killTweensOf();
```

Comment: It doesn't work it keeps tweening I put it like this: if(s.hitTestObject(ends)){
  TweenLite.killTweensOf(s);
  s.x = -125.9;
  s.y = 375.6;
  
  }}

Comment: TweenLite.killTweensOf(s); will stop the tween. Perhaps your issue is to do with how you are trying to implement it. i.e. perhaps s.hitTestObject(ends) is never true.

Comment: maybe it is because I put it in an addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME  because s.hitTestObject(ends) is true